# Should whitespace be generally consumed at start or end of a syntax?

Tags: parsing, formal-languages

I've started using FParsec. This is the first time i'm writing a parser using "grammar" and not just coding the behaviour. I'm trying to figure out how white space should generally be treated: At start of any given syntax? At the end? Depends? And why?

For example, should `SymbolIdentifier` parse the leading white space in "... abc ...", or should it be consumed by a previous syntax?

Comment: FParsec requires you to manually add whitespace into your rules. http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#handling-whitespace This contrasts with other parser generators and language specs that move whitespace recognition out of the grammar, which results in a cleaner grammar. For a lexical analyzer, whitespace is read before the token, including the end-of-file token. So I would place whitespace recognition only before an FParsec string literal or primitive.

Comment: I don't have a huge amount of experience with writing scannerless grammars, but for what it's worth, in the few such grammars I've written, what's worked best for me is to only (and always) recognise whitespace *between* components (unless, of course, the components must not be separated by whitespace), and neither at the beginning nor the end, except for the top-level syntax.